# Processing problems with Fix Geometries for large polygons

Tags: qgis

**Description**

I am working with uploads of geometries for potential flooding and erosion areas. Since most of the geometries made for these areas, are highly detailed and seem "large" for Qgis to handle - i often meet problems and/or crashes when attempting to run several tools. An example would be "fix geometries" which i use to fix self-intersects and such, but the processing time for this tool can take 15-30 minutes, if above ~30 min, Qgis often crash.

I have also tried to simplify the geometry first, but still i meet the processing problems with fix geometries. The same problem is met for the buffer tool, making the "dissolve" work-around impossible.

**Question**

Does anyone know, how i can mitigate any of these problems for large geometries, other than fix geometries? Also, is there a "cap" on how large geometries (how many verticies etc), a geometry may have, in order for Qgis tools to work well?

**The specific idea**

I am currently constructing a Qgis model to correct these "large complex" geometries, which often consists of 10.000+ features. The model is quite simpel, and i have shared an image down below. It will first rinse the geometry for polygons less than "x" m2, next it will fix the geometries in order to collect them into a single feature. Then, a second fix is needed in order to use the simplify tool, and then again a third fix. All 3 fix geometry steps is needed, since the error message "Invalid geometry, please fix (...)) will appear if i dont. Lastly, i split the single feature into 5 equal sizes by using random points, cluster them, aggregate them and finally centroid them. The last part is using voronoi polygons on the centroids, and intersect with the original polygon, resulting in 5 equal size polygons, that have been simplified, making them acceptable for upload on the website.
[image]

Fingers-crossed

Comment: If you fix geometries one by one, does it work? So first just fixing one feature, then the next etc. If this works, you could maybe run generalize in batch mode?

Comment: @Babel the specific layer i am testing on contains 8.300 features. If i run Fix Geometries on a single feature, it works fine. But it would take a lot of time to go through every single feature and fixing them. So i believe this is out of the question. 
I have tried searching for generalize, but i can only seem to find "Smooth", is this the same? There is a generalize for Qgis Grass, but i cant installa Grass because im working on a office computer which is restricted.